# How to get default /usr/share/vim folder back?

Tags: package-management, vim

I was messing with by profile and ended up deleting `/usr/share/vim` folder and everything in it. How can I get this folder back?

> sudo aptitude reinstall vim

did not help

basically I would want vim and gvim to be back to 'factory settings' ...for this i'll need original `.vimrc` as well

Answer (score 3):

The /usr/share/vim folder has files from `vim-runtime`, `vim-common`, `vim-gui-common` and `vim-tiny` packages.  Reinstall them all.

Comment: Only need to run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall vim vim-runtime vim-common`

Answer (score 2):

Delete/backup all the files for vim under /home/*youruser*. If you use it as root, under /root as well. I recommend a .tar backup. Then run:

> sudo apt-get purge vim

Finally run:

> sudo apt-get install vim

That should do it.

Comment: I tried this but it says 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.